# JOptionPane output black window

Tags: java, runtime-error, joptionpane

I have problem with JOptionPane output. When I click button to show output in JOptionPane It show right output but then after + - 1sec it turns to black.. Sometimes it turns black instantly without showing right output :( Output is this:

[image]

and my code is

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00"); 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jPrint,
    "number is"+ df.format(amount),
    "Output",
    JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```

I dont see anything wrong here in code.. Can problem be somewhere in my PC? Because on other PC (in work) it works right.

Comment: could you post more codes somewhere like pastebin

Comment: did you use threads in your code ?

Comment: I didnt use threads..

Comment: I had similar experiences with a corrupted vga driver. Try changing the windows theme, like turning on/off aero, or simply switch to Basic theme just to see what happens. If you see any positive change, update/reinstall the vga driver.

Comment: OMG ! Thank you very much... It helped. Changed windows aero to windows basic. Thank you ! :)